# Sort an array of objects based on a numeric key given as String

Tags: javascript

I have an an array with key-value pair, array columns are id and name. I want to sort this array by id.

The id column value is of type string type but I want to sort them as numeric values.

```
var items = [
{
    "id": "165",
    "name": "a"
},
{
    "id": "236",
    "name": "c"
},
{
    "id": "376",
    "name": "b"
},
{
    "id": "253",
    "name": "f"
},
{
    "id": "235",
    "name": "e"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "name": "d"
},
{
    "id": "26",
    "name": "d"
}
]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. What is your actual question?

Comment: Not Possible duplicate value according to my code BraveButter

Comment: My question is I want to sort this array by Id column but when i sort it on server side code it shows 1,10,100,11,111,12,2 which is wrong i want 1,2,34.... Krishna Prashatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Arrays.sort()`

```js
var arr = [{"id":"165","name":"a"},{"id":"236","name":"c"},{"id":"376","name":"b"},{"id":"253","name":"f"},{"id":"235","name":"e"},{"id":"24","name":"d"},{"id":"26","name":"d"}];
arr.sort((a,b)=> Number(a.id) - Number(b.id));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Anshul ie doest not support arrow functions, replace arrow function write function(a,b). And please mark answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Yes you are right It is working after changing arrow to function(a,b). @amrender singh

Answer (score 4):

```
items.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id)
```

Comment: This won't work on older browsers, but is widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [
{
    "id": "165",
    "name": "a"
},
{
    "id": "236",
    "name": "c"
},
{
    "id": "376",
    "name": "b"
},
{
    "id": "253",
    "name": "f"
},
{
    "id": "235",
    "name": "e"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "name": "d"
},
{
    "id": "26",
    "name": "d"
}];
items.sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id));
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [
{
    "id": "165",
    "name": "a"
},
{
    "id": "236",
    "name": "c"
},
{
    "id": "376",
    "name": "b"
},
{
    "id": "253",
    "name": "f"
},
{
    "id": "235",
    "name": "e"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "name": "d"
},
{
    "id": "26",
    "name": "d"
}];

// for asscending
items.sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id));
console.log(items);
// for descending
items.sort((a, b) => Number(b.id) - Number(a.id));
console.log(items);
```

Comment: isn't the logic for descending order should be `-a+b` instead of `a+b`

Answer (score 0):

The numeric strings can be compared in many ways. Suppose the strings are `a` and `b`,

1. `a-b`
2. `parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)` - Reference - [Java Script parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
3. `+a - +b` - Reference - [Unary `+` operator to convert string to number](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce)
4. `Number(a) - Number(b)` - Reference - [Javascript Global Number Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
var items = [{"id": "165","name": "a"},{"id": "236","name": "c"},{"id": "376","name": "b"},{"id": "253","name": "f"},{"id": "235","name": "e"},{"id": "24","name": "d"},{"id": "26","name": "d"}];

console.log(items.sort(function(a,b){ return parseInt(a.id)-parseInt(b.id) }));
console.log(items.sort(function(a,b){ return a.id-b.id }));
console.log(items.sort(function(a,b){ return +a.id - +b.id }));
console.log(items.sort(function(a,b){ return Number(a.id)-Number(b.id) }));
```

Comment: @Anshul FYI, you can also use the unary `+` to convert and compare them

Comment: Yes First one is working properly Because I was getting error on IE when using Arrow (=>) sign. Thanks @Vignesh Raja