# Preserve javascript key order when they're integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been doing some reading and may have missed the obvious but don't think I have.

I have the following code:

```
var res = JSON.parse('{"products":{"0":"Please Select","2":"Example 1","3":"Example 2","4":"Example 3","5":"Example 4","88":"Example 5","7":"Example 6","8":"Example 7"}}');

for (key in res.products){
  $('#myList').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+res.products[key]+'</option>');
}
```

Which I would like to add to a simple empty `<select>` element using Jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/htrdzyqo/

However the order is putting Example 5 at the bottom not in its correct place. After reading, I appreciate that object keys are not properly ordered ([Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129)) and that JSON keys cannot be integers ([Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/)). I need to *preserve* the object order rather than being auto-sorted. The reason being as its an ID must remain intact (so no Array alternative).

Am I missing something simple or do I need to rethink/work this?

Comment: "*I need to sort by the numeric*" - but `88` is numerically larger than the other ids, so it would still end up at the bottom, which is not what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array of objects based on a numeric key given as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080370/sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-a-numeric-key-given-as-string)

Comment: What do you mean by "*so no Array alternative*"? Yes, you should be using an array for the products if you care about order: `{"products": [ {"key": 0, "text": "Please Select"}, {"key": 2, "text": "Example 1"}, … ]}`. It's the only proper solution.

Comment: Sorry you are right - I will adjust my question - I want the order preserved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON, by definition, the name/value pairs in an **object** `{}` are unordered: They have no specific order in which they appear. In a **list** `[]` on the other hand, the order is preserved.

See also [this other StackOverflow question where the answer cites the official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-preserved).

As @Bergi already pointed out in the comments, putting products into a list is the proper solution.

```js
JSON.parse('{"products": [ {"key": 0, "text": "Please Select"}, {"key": 2, "text": "Example 1"}, ... ]}');

for (let product of res.products) {
  $('#myList').append('<option value="'+product.key+'">'+product.text+'</option>');
}
```

Comment: Super - good example. Unfortunate it has to work this way but it is indeed the way to do it.